# Does jQuery slow down the rendering of webpages by 100ms or more?

Tags: jquery, performance, frontend

I am trying to improve the frontend page load speed for users, and I am finding that jQuery is slowing the DomContentLoaded event down by more than 100ms.

I am benchmarking on Windows 7 with Chrome 17 using a computer with an i5 2.5Ghz, SSD drive, and 8GB of RAM. The test is run on my local computer. I'm concerned that the slow speed I see on my machine will be even slower on older computers and browsers.

Is this just the standard penalty for using jQuery, or is there a way to speed up the performance that I am missing?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.time("DOMContentLoaded");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", ready, false );

            function ready() {
                console.timeEnd("DOMContentLoaded");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the console, the time that I see is roughly ~100ms.

When I remove the line that loads jQuery, the time is roughly ~1ms.

I also tried the code above using the Google CDN:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result is largely the same.

Is there always a 100ms penalty for using jQuery? Is there something that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Try to put the code inside the DOM ready with jQuery: `$(ready);`

Comment: Hi gdoron - this 100ms delay seems to be do to simply loading jQuery, without actually running other javascript. It appears that would only help for additional javascript.

Comment: This recent article may be relevant to your interests: "[Stop Paying The jQuery Tax](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax)" by @[Sam Saffron](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron)

Comment: Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) instead of loading the file locally.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: That would result in worse time results for his current test. Thats only going to reduce the load on his server. I assume he is using a local copy to remove that as a factor from his test results. I get about 32ms loading locally, and about 80ms using a CDN. I'm sure its like Sam Saffron said, and its just the time it takes to use jquery.

Comment: In general the parse and compile time is 10ms to 80ms+ depending on browser and HD speed, first vs second hit and a variety of other factors ... this hit is constant and happens every time you load up a page.

Answer (score 5):

You are going to see a small hit whenever loading a large JS library like jQuery. Personally, I'd argue that 100ms isn't much, you have to keep in mind ALL of the factors leading to this:

1. You are timing the load, which takes time.
2. Your network connection plays a factor (there's parse document, make request, wait for response). Latency of your connection must be factored in (use http://www.speedtest.net to test your latency, and subtract that from the 100ms+ to get a better idea of the actual hit).
3. Proper cache control on your web server can all but eliminate #2, configure that server so the file only expires once every month or so. This header will then be passed with the file so the user's browser only loads it once a month. You will still incur the small request on the first page load, but at least then subsequent page requests will pull it from the local cache reducing this time.
4. There's parse an execution time; The ENTIRE jQuery file needs to be parsed, and executed. Minifying only reduces the size, and therefore the bandwidth required to transfer it (which equates to time based on connection speed)... minifying does very little to reduce parse time (modern JS engines like V8 fly over comments and whitespace as if they weren't even there).

Keep in mind, that most pages won't have NEARLY as much custom JS (based on jQuery) as the actual library itself, so even an intensively interactive page will only see a few [dozen] milliseconds of additional overhead over what the library itself has already imposed.

As for people with old machines/browsers; chances are they're experiencing poor performance on every page they visit. The web is a dynamic place, you have to keep up if you want to have a good experience. There's only so much you can do for luddites.

Comment: Hi Gregory -- on points 2 and 3, I should have noted that I was running the test locally and using an SSD hard drive, so the latency should be minimal.

Comment: Locally from an SSD certainly does get pretty close to no overhead. Getting similar results from from Google's CDN, I think, proves pretty well that due to parse/execution, you probably just won't get any better... I still stand by my last paragraph :)

Comment: My guess is the delay is due to the parsing of jQuery. You proabably want to look at the load of the page using webpagetest.org, or HTTPWatch to see this delay rather than relying on javascript to work it out for you (which might introduce other issues with the small duration we're talking about)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a 92K file. You have to load it and parse it.

I have hosted your example at studio831.com/jquery_test/index.html, cdn.html, and dom_ready.html.

You can look at the times each take to download. You can also use Chrome's developer tools to see the breakdown how long downloads takes.

Comment: These all perform exactly the same for me once jquery has been cached. Multiple reloads perform equally in terms of the time being spent just parsing jquery.

Answer (score -3):

The slowdown that you see is because the browser has to download the jQuery library first. This is the "penalty" you get when you include any external javascript. It has nothing to do with jQuery.

You can minimize this by using a script loader such as require.js.

Comment: It has something to do with jquery though. Even if you load the entire thing as a local file, there is parse time for jquery, as minimal is it might be.

Comment: Hi blockhead -- in the tests, I was loading jQuery locally. I also tried loading it off of the Google CDN and measuring the time on subsequent page loads when the library was already cached.

Comment: How could require.js minimize the slowdown?

Comment: @ElisByberi by 1) bundling all the scripts into one, 2) allowing you to minimize the script, thus sending less bytes over the wire.

Comment: @blockhead 1. Bundling will not load scripts faster, not in 2012 using TCP Connection Reuse, not today using HTTP2.  2. require.js have nothing to minimize to jquery.min.js